# Should You Honor the Local Pronunciation

Tags: word-usage, american-english, pronunciation

[Vote to reopen if you think the spoken language is worth exploring, and I think ELU includes the word 'usage']

Should you pronounce a word according to the region in which you are, as best you can?

For example, if someone is from Nevada, where everyone would pronounce 'advertisement' similar to adver *tise* ment, would it be considered pretentious if they pronounced it ad *vert* isement?

The french pastry has a an obvious longstanding pronunciation in American English as 'kruh-sahnt' (croissant). If an American then says 'krwah-sahn', particularly to another American, it seems out of place and disruptive to the conversation.

Another example is when a non-spanish speaker (I'm looking at you NPR), pronounces latin surnames and countries with a (sometimes heavy) spanish enunciation. Rodriguez can have a heavy spanish pronunciation, but then they pronounce Mexico in the American pronunciation, i.e. not 'Me-he-co'. It's inconsistent and annoying.

Is pronunciation relevant?

Should pronunciation, and even spelling (color vs. colour) be more conscientious of the speaker/listener relationship, and is not doing so, considered rude or pretentious?

When you learn a word, do you not ask "how does it sound?"

Comment: You're asking a sociological and psychological question here, not one regarding the correct usage of the English language. You're going to get different answers from different people, if you get any at all. This question is both out of place and is not constructive as a result.

Comment: While matters of Dialect differences and Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology) are within scope of the ELU, this question seems to be about the etiquette of using pronunciations and as such would seem to be out of scope for the site. I always hesitate to tell someone they are in the wrong place though, as I'm still quite new here myself, and would value other opinions.

Comment: I fail to see how pronunciation of a single word one way or the other can be "disruptive to a conversation". Too much noise or screaming kids might be, though.

Comment: I understand that this might be a fringe question and I considered that before posting. I think though, it has plenty of precedence on this site, particularly in the form of 'Usage'. For example, you'd probably caution someone on the use of 'femme fatale'. What's acceptable in one setting might not be in another. Pronunciation seems like a logical extension of how we use words and the risk they carry when we use them.

Comment: @RMac, I disagree. A discussion on various pronunciations and spellings of words is constructive. It's my thought that context, usage, and their effect on the listener is very interesting and important to people who want to improve their language skills.

Comment: @John Your question is about the ways people might interpret variance from a regional norm. This question has everything to do with people's tolerances and attitudes toward their own and other cultures and nothing to do with correct use of the English language (especially since all the accents in the scope of your consideration are "correct", after a fashion). Your question cannot be answered without a large scale sociological study, and the features of the study and of the answer both would exceed the scope of grammatical consideration.

Comment: Is it pretentious to say *noo-klee-ar* rather than *noo-cue-lar* in the South? I really don't think so. Is it pretentious to pronounce *omelette* with a Frenchish accent, i.e. *ohm-LET* with the accent on the second syllable? Unless you're from France, it clearly is.

Comment: @PeterShor, Right, and wouldn't it at least be weird (and not pretentious in this case) if a Bostonian started going around saying 'noo-cue-lar'? These are examples of incorrect or improper form though. When you look at examples where both are correct though, then it starts to become a question of tolerability and that's what's interesting to me. But alas, it seems it will have to be a question left to ponder yonder.

Comment: @John:  Who are you to say that *noo-cue-lar* is incorrect, when there is a whole swath of the country that pronounces it that way? Also, I am not going to start pronouncing *car-mell* as *care-a-mell* no matter where I am, and I don't see why anybody else should either.

Comment: This question is independent of what language one is speaking. If you want this to be an English question, you might be able to ask about the register or regionality of a particular word or phrase. For example, how do *ad-VER-tise-ment* and *AD-ver-tise-ment* compare in terms of formality, education signal, region, subculture, etc.

Comment: @PeterShor, you're right. But then there's the matter of pecan pie. Since pecans (pi'cons) only grow (veritably) in the South, isn't it just plain ignorant to call it pee-can pie?

Comment: @John It's never "plain ignorant" for anyone to call anything whatever they've grown up calling it. I'm concerned about your assumptions here.

Comment: @tchrist, it's fine. I was joking. All-in-all, it's about how to pronounce a pie. And who doesn't like merengue?

Comment: @tchrist, I'm curious I guess, what assumptions you think I've made. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: John, 'should' questions don't work well on SE. Is it "When in Rome, do as the Romans do" or "Be true to yourself"? There are so many sociological things going on, ethnicity, power, perception, standards. One says 'ne VAH da', the other says the first is an ass, or is out of state, or calls him 'sir'. It is too variable to say.

Comment: @Mitch, maybe they ask first, take a breath and say all of that. But, hey, at least they know the Rome thing. Maybe even how to pronounce a state. Sociologically speaking, the question is, do people want to know how to communicate better? Go do a survey I guess. I believe it's self evident. I certainly believe it's worth asking all those questions. Hell, not asking is just plain stupid.

Comment: @Mitch, but, very funny. Thank you. I think reopening this would be an interesting precedent and a good precedent.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I think it would be deemed odd to pronounce something in a manner different to the vernacular, especially if you are mostly speaking in the vernacular.  Whether it is deemed pretentious or not will depend on the pronunciation and the person.

For instance if you spoke in RP (Queen's English) any English speaking nations other than England, and probably even in parts of England, it would likely sound pretentious.

On the other hand, if you say foreign words with their foreign pronunciation (think croissant, or Macedonia, etc) people will think you are saying the word oddly and it may even hinder their understanding a little ("what is Makedonia?"), but they may or may not think it's rude or pretentious.  If they feel you are insinuating they are pronouncing words incorrectly, they may be offended.

Comment: "[...] I think [...]," is a feature every answer to this question must necessarily have in common. Viewers of this question should be careful not to take these answers as fact, as they represent only the opinion of the person giving the answer.

Comment: @RMac, a vast amount of the English language was created based on consensus. You'd want someone to tell you not to extend your left hand in Saudi Arabia even though you think it's fine. Tipping is great, unless you're in Japan. And you'd probably want someone to tell you your 'okay' sign is not very nice in Brazil. Language is no different and regional distinctions are not guided by opinion.